# group an array by name and age

Tags: php, arrays, json

can you help me please, I have this PHP from which I get an array. But I want to change its output and be able to group them by name and age.

This is my PHP

```
<?php

    $name = array();
    $age  = array();

    $sql = $conn->runQuery("SELECT * FROM staff");
    $sql->execute();
    
    while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $name[] = $row['name'];
            $age[]  = $row['age'];
        }

    $posts = [
        "name"  => $name,
        "age"   => $age,
    ];

    echo json_encode($posts, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

 ?>
```

this is the result.

```
{
    "name": [
        "Erik",
        "Rose",
        "Abby",
        "Abner"
    ],
    "age": [
        "18",
        "28",
        "25",
        "22"
    ]
}
```

But, I would like the array to return as follows.

```
[
  {
    "name": Erik,
    "age": 18
  },
  {
    "name": Rose,
    "age": 28
  }
]
```

Can you help me please, how do I have to make this kind of array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adjustment I would make to this script is as follows:

```
$sql = $conn->runQuery("SELECT * FROM staff");
$sql->execute();

$people = [];
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
   $people[] = ['name' => $row['name'], 'age' => $row['age']];
}
echo json_encode($people, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Thank you, your comment helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Or use [`fetchAll()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) :

```
$qry = $conn->prepare("SELECT field1, field2 FROM table");
$qry->execute();

$data = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($data);
```